# How to copy only files from many subdirectory under the directory to another project bucket in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have huge number of data in my Google Cloud storage bucket. I have to copy all the files to another project bucket. But the main problem is, in this bucket i created some folder and under this folder have many sub-folders and all sub-folders have data. So when i am using normal gsutil copy command then its copying all the data along with folders.
I need help to resolve this problem. Because it is taking too much time to copy from one project to another project bucket.

Comment: Unclear what the problem is. Is it that it is taking too much time to copy or it is copying files you don't want to copy?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this command to have all the files in the root path.

```
gsutil cp 'gs://[YOUR_FIRST_BUCKET_NAME]/*' gs://[YOUR_SECOND_BUCKET_NAME]
```

If you have **nested directories** inside your bucket, use this command:

```
gsutil cp -r 'gs://[YOUR_FIRST_BUCKET_NAME]/*' gs://[YOUR_SECOND_BUCKET_NAME]
```

Pay attention to single quotes around the first command.
You can take a look at the [Wildcard Names](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames) if you need more advanced features.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use [Google Data Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console)

It is the second option in the `Google Cloud Storage` subcategory.

Comment: But i have to copy all files from one project bucket to other project bucket. And in this transfer method i am not able to select my destination.

Comment: @ChandanThakur if you have the write access, you can transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gsutil cp` command without -r option.

> The -R and -r options are synonymous. Causes directories,
>                    buckets, and bucket subdirectories to be copied recursively.
>                    If you neglect to use this option for an upload, gsutil will
>                    copy any files it finds and skip any directories. Similarly,
>                    neglecting to specify this option for a download will cause
>                    gsutil to copy any objects at the current bucket directory
>                    level, and skip any subdirectories.

Comment: When i neglect -R and -r then i am getting error like ommiting prefix.

Comment: This is useful when you have to copy files from bucket not from bucket/folder/sub-folder/files. Here i have to copy files from bucket/folders/subfolders/files to another project bucket.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to copy all the files from one bucket to another bucket, but you don't want to have the same hierarchy, instead, you want to have all the files in the root path.

Nowadays there’s no possible way to do that with gsutil, but you can do it with a script, here you have my solution:

```py
from google.cloud import storage
bucketOrigin = storage.Client().get_bucket("<BUCKET_ID_ORIGIN>")
bucketDestination = storage.Client().get_bucket("<BUCKET_ID_DESTINATION")
for blob in bucketOrigin.list_blobs():
    strfile=blob.download_as_string()
    blobDest = bucketDestination.blob(blob.name[blob.name.rfind("/")+1:])
    blobDest.upload_from_string(strfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Akash Dathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5924523/akash-dathan), you can use the **Cloud Storage Transfer Service** to move your bucket content. I recommend you to take a look on this [Moving and Renaming Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets) guide, where you can find the steps required to perform this task.

Bear in mind the following requirments:

- Transfer Service service account must have permission to read from
  your source and write to your destination.
- If you're deleting the source files, the Transfer Service's service account will need delete access to the source.
- If your service account doesn't have these
  permissions yet, a bucket owner must grant them.

**Note.** If you have ***'storage.buckets.setIamPolicy'*** permission for the source and destination buckets, creating a transfer job will grant that service account the required source and destination permissions to complete the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all files from your subfolders and get the file name by using `split()` method. Then you can use use a `copy()` method to copy the file to another bucket. The method below remove all subfolders:

```
    const [files] = await storage.bucket(srcBucketName).getFiles();
    files.forEach((file) => {
      let fileName = file.name.split("/").pop();
      if (fileName) 
        file.copy(storage.bucket(destBucketName).file(`${prefix}/${fileName}`));

    });
```