# Moving only folder with specific file extensions from one folder to another in Google Cloud Storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to move all the folders and sub-folders which contain py files from one parent folder to another in GCS Bucket.

Folder A which contain the files I want to copy look something like this:

```
FOLDER_A
|              
+---PROJECT_A
|       Project_A_PROD.py
|       Project_A - flow chart.png
|       README.md
|                      
\---Project_B_APAC
|   +---Project_B1_APAC
|   |       Project_B1_APAC_flow_chart.png
|   |       Project_B1_APAC.py
|   |       README.md
|   |       
|   +---Project_B2_APAC
|   |       Project_B2_APAC.py
|   |       Project_B2_APAC_flow_chart.png
|   |       README.md
|   |       
|   \---Project_B3_APAC
|           Project_B3_APAC.py
|           Project_B3_APAC_flow_chart.png
|           README.md
```

And the folder B where I want to move the py files should look like this:

```
FOLDER_B
|              
+---PROJECT_A
|       Project_A_PROD.py
|                      
\---Project_B_APAC
|   +---Project_B1_APAC
|   |       Project_B1_APAC.py
|   |       
|   +---Project_B2_APAC
|   |       Project_B2_APAC.py
|   |       
|   \---Project_B3_APAC
|           Project_B3_APAC.py
```

Both the folders are present in the same bucket.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As GCS does  have "prefixes" rather than "folders" - did you try `gsutil ls -r gs://bucket/prefix/**.py` or without '-r': `gsutil ls gs://bucket/prefix/**.py` Details are here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls and here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames  In your case, you might need to use the `cp` command with `-m` flag - somthing like: `gsutil -m cp ...`

Comment: You need to write a small script to do that, nothing out of the box

Comment: Have a look at both of these stackoverflow thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959784/move-only-certain-files-to-gcp-and-keep-subfolder) & (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420201/how-to-copy-only-files-from-many-subdirectory-under-the-directory-to-another-pro)